# Enabling multidex error: finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: java, android

I got this error after adding multidex library:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

When I fix it by enabling multidex in `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig{
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

but after that I got another error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

or value 1

I will appreciate  if some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use custom `Application` class in your project you should inherit it from `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` to make multidex work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and to the "application" tag in the manifest add this line:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Comment: i can't add  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" because i have singletion in my app

Comment: <application
        android:name=".app.Singleton"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: yes it does and also i add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' but it did'nt work